# SharePoint 2019 - On-premise - Grant permissions to add / edit event.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, events

I am hoping someone can offer some guidance here.

We have SP2019 On-premise install. I have a request to open permissions to just the Events.aspx pages to create /edit /delete.

Is there a way to grant access to just this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Events.aspx page doesn't exist in a vacuum. It is always connected to an Events list. You can open the Events list of the respective site, which will show as a classic calendar with a ribbon interface. On the Calendar ribbon tab, click List Settings, then click "Permissions for this list".

Stop inheriting permissions and add the desired people with Edit permissions. These people will now be able to add, edit and delete events on the site.

**Edit after comment:** If the event editors also need to be able to upload custom images to the header, they need Edit access to the Site Assets library as well, so you need to change the permissions for that library, too.

Another option is to set the site to Edit access for everybody, then break permissions for each content library and change it to Read for some groups and Edit for others. That way you have permissions for any built-in system lists covered.

Comment: Thanks teylyn - this approach has already been undertaken. The issue is when opening an events page and editing the content and banner images which the 'Edit' permissions do not allow.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. I had gathered this must be case. Appreciate the fuller response.

Comment: @garvon-77 If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.